# XAML binding with x reference does not work, but same binding with code works - why?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui

I have a ContentView which exposes a boolean property,  which you can bind to:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowCurrentIntervalInfoProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ShowCurrentIntervalInfo), typeof(bool), typeof(WorkoutTimerBottomView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool ShowCurrentIntervalInfo
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(ShowCurrentIntervalInfoProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShowCurrentIntervalInfoProperty, value);
    }
```

In the XAML of this ContentView, there are controls whose values are bound to this property. Now for the sakes of demonstrating my issue, consider the two following labels, and the button:

```
    <Label x:Name="label1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference workoutTimerBottomView}, Path=ShowCurrentIntervalInfo}"/>
    <Label x:Name= "label2"/>
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

And the behind code:

```
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (propertyName == nameof(ShowCurrentIntervalInfo))
        {
            label2.Text = ShowCurrentIntervalInfo.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowCurrentIntervalInfo = !ShowCurrentIntervalInfo;
    }
```

-> Now, when I click on the button, the text of label2 does switch from True to False, thanks to code from OnPropertyChanged shown above, but the text from label1 stays bound to False.

I'm not sure if this is a known issue or if I'm misunderstanding something about bindings?

(Note: The name of the ContentView instance is consistant with the x:Reference, this is in the ContentView tag)

```
x:Name="workoutTimerBottomView"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BindableProperty can [detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes). So you could register a property-changed callback method in `BindableProperty.Create` method. This method will detect value changes of **ShowCurrentIntervalInfoProperty**. You could then add some logic (for example set the value for label2) in it. Please consider my code below,

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ShowCurrentIntervalInfoProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ShowCurrentIntervalInfo), typeof(bool), typeof(WorkoutTimerBottomView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,propertyChanged:OnInfoPropertyChanged);

private static void OnInfoPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var obj = bindable as WorkoutTimerBottomView;
    obj.label2.Text = newValue.ToString();
}
```

Then you don't have to use **OnPropertyChanged** method in code behind.

Hope it helps!